# Difference between Visa refusal appeal and Fresh application

Tags: visa-refusals, schengen-visas, visa-refusal-appeal

I am planning to appeal my Visa refusal, however there are few points which I want to clarify.

- Am I allowed to submit additional documents/details along with my appeal to prove my case? If yes then how is it different from new application.
- Should my appeal be in native language? In my case should I submit my appeal to Hungarian embassy in Hungarian or English is fine. Nowhere it was mentioned to submit the appeal in Hungarian.
- If translation is required then, can I use google translate or do I need to get translation stamped by people offering translation services.

Answer (score 2):

The process to appeal a refusal is:

- Applicants may appeal within 8 calendar days from the day of receipt of the official refusal document.
- Applicants should write in A4 paper a letter of appeal to the Ministry of Foreign Affairs of Hungary in Hungarian or any other language of the European Union explaining his/her situation and the reason of appeal. However, if the appeal is provided in other language than Hungarian or English then it is necessary to present official translation of it in Hungarian or English.
- Present to the Consular Department the written appeal letter, official refusal document, passport and additional documents which applicant considers important for the appeal process
- Pay the €160 fee

The documents will be sent to the Ministry of Foreign Affairs of Hungary and it takes 15 days. Once the process finishes the MFA of Hungary informs the Consular Section about the results which in its turn immediately contacts the applicant to give the necessary information. The Consul may interview the applicant at the time of appeal.

Source: [https://baku.mfa.gov.hu/eng/page/procedure-of-appeal#:~:text=Applicants%20may%20appeal%20within%208,and%20the%20reason%20of%20appeal](https://baku.mfa.gov.hu/eng/page/procedure-of-appeal#:%7E:text=Applicants%20may%20appeal%20within%208,and%20the%20reason%20of%20appeal)